# Doughnut tutorials by Blender Guru

Tags: render, blender

I followed all the tutorials by Blender Guru (Andrew Price) to make doughnut and coffee to the animation stage. When I render the project the icing is missing from all files even though it is clearly visible in the view-port. I am guessing that I have somehow un-linked it in the out-liner but not certain. I have tried to find where the error is but cannot. 
The icing is correctly parented to the doughnut so moves with it in animation. 
The icing is not excluded from render by the camera icon in the out-liner. 
Has any one got any useful suggestions that I can try?

Comment: Try to add a clear example of what is not working and how the output should be.

Comment: prp Is it possible for me to attach a picture in this thread that I have prepared? It will demonstrate the issue more clearly.

Comment: Though I apologise for the poor image quality, this does show the problem
https://virtualpreston.co.uk/comparison.html